# Can I degrade back to 3.7.1 from 3.8 by just coping old wp files?

Tags: upgrade

I just want to downgrade back to 3.7.1  from 3.8

Easiest thing to do is just replace old wp files and overwrite new 3.8 files.

Will there be any issues if I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - who knows. Will probably work, maybe something will explode. Behavior is undefined for backwards direction.

Long answer - from quick look at code 3.8 upgrade doesn't *seem* to do anything specific to database, so *likely* it will be pretty painless. For any serious site - make a staging copy and test it thoroughly.